# Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com [Network is unreachable #101] on Godaddy

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, office365, contactus

I am setting up a contact us page on Laravel website using a office 365 email. The set up work great on Bluehost but did not work on Godaddy hosting, I suspect the reason maybe the TXT record. Here is what I currently have :

v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:servers.mcsv.net include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:secureserver.net -all

Please let me know if it's correct?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikhZM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think the mail driver is set to **smtp**.

Try changing the mail driver from **smtp** to **sendmail**, as smtp mail driver on godaddy hosting can not properly establish connection with mail server.

For Reference see the following configuration:

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx@xxxxx.xx

MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls